# HTTP server connection management

Tags: http, server

I've been playing around with an `http` server I'm creating using `boost::asio` (hence the c++ tag).

With `HTTP/1.1` the default is to keep the clients connection open for more than 1 request/response.

**My question is:**

How long should I keep a client connection open? Should I use a `deadline_timer` which closes the connection after some arbitrary amount of time?

Or, should I just wait for the underlying socket receive timeout to expire? At which point my `receive` handler will be invoked with an `EOF` error prompting me to remove the client connection from my list of connections.

Furthermore, if this is specified in an `RFC` document, which one?

Comment: Is this for a general server serving pages, or for a REST API endpoint?

Comment: @Frank Sending pages

Comment: _"With HTTP/1.1 the default is to keep the clients connection open for more than 1 request/response."_ Where did you hear that?

Comment: Google "HTTP RFC" and you'll find the spec(s)...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Everywhere

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Again, I have read multiple RFC documents but nothing concerning `HTTP server connection management`. If you're saying different, then please enlighten me.

Comment: "Everywhere" = where exactly? I've never heard such a thing. Keep-Alive is optional. In fact the MDN page links to the RFC you probably want. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Try reading this document instead. A persistent connection **is** the default. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection

Comment: @WBuck Okay, so it is!